# Why do I need to press the shutter twice on my Canon 450D?

Tags: lens

I am using 450d. When using a-def,m,av,tv,p mode, the shutter does not work properly.  After pressing the shutter button, you have to press it again to lower the shutter. Do you have a solution?  Also, AF is not possible when using the above mode.

Answer (score 5):

Your camera has “Mirror Lockup” enabled. You need to go into the Custom Function menu and disable CF III-9.

Here is a link to a short video that describes this in more detail.

[Canon XSi/EOS 450D: Mirror Lockup](https://youtu.be/tI9OccTmkcM)

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much